# Latex already defined clash between cls file and multiple packages

Tags: packages, templates, incompatibility

I am using `sjvour3.cls` provided by springer which define `\keywords` command. Many other packages also define this command and when compiling with latex, I get this error.

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \keywords already
>   defined.

I cannot change the `cls` file as they would use their standard version to compile my paper. It complains in many packages `multirow`, `subfig`, `float`, `fontenc` etc.

[EDIT] I fixed this issue by using `\let\keywords\relax` command after `\documentclass`.

Comment: You might want to consider cutting down on the number of packages you use, such that you are not using packages that provide `\keywords`. In general, for articles for journals, only use the packages that are essential for this particular article.

Comment: I completely agree with @daleif.  You should only use the minimal required packages, specially because the class usually includes everything you need.  Please try to run it on "minimal system" and see how it does

Comment: I don't think that *many* packages define `\keywords`. Surely `multirow`, `subfig`, `float` and `fontenc` don't.

Comment: You mention in the follow-up to your posting that you've "fixed the issue" by providing the instruction `\let\keywords\relax` after `\documentclass`. This is likely more oa band-aid than a real fix unless, miraculously, the `\keywords` macro provided by one of the packages you're loading has the same properties as the `\keywords` macro set up by the `sjvour3` document class.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your clarification. I don't know any way other than removing those packages or changing cls or sty files.

Comment: @user600029 do you mind mentioning which packages you are using. I can find little more than a handfull `.sty` files that provides a `\keywords` macro. And most are quire exotic.

Comment: @user600029, that fix you are using might not be suitable with what `sjvour3` is doing (different syntax etc). Thus you may end up annoying the editors of that particular journal.

Comment: The packages I find in the TeX Live distribution that define `\keywords` are `beamerbasestyle`, `agupp`, `asaetr`, `cmpj`, `cmpj2`, `csbulletin`, `stepv13`, `kluopen`, `blog`, `ltxfront` and `titlefoot`. Which one are you loading?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear as there are information lacking to answer the question in a satisdying way.

Comment: @user600029, if you have solved your problem you can still edit your question so that you can answer to egreg's inquiry. By doing so, users can solve your issue in the correct way. This might not matters a lot to you, but in the future, others with similar problem can benefit from this post.